# UITableViewCellStyleValue1 Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I'm making a app
And i keep getting a error at this spot

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]] autorelease];
```

and these are errors;

> UITableViewCellStyleValue1 was not declared in this scope no
>   '-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:' method found

please help, and thanks.
Please tell me if you need to see full code..

Comment: What #imports do you have in the file?

Comment: #import "RootViewController.h"
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the full code to get some context, but try this:

- First close the project if it's open.
- In the xcode menu bar, go to Window -> Organizer.
- Go to the projects tab and select your project from the list on the left.
- Where it says Derived Data, click the delete button and open your project back up.

Try building it or running it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Im coding with THEOS on iDevice so its different i will post full code onto post in like 1-2 minutes..

Answer (score 0):

Ok your problem is in /theos/ include/ uikit the headers are one for uikit2 I believe if u go in /var/sdk/system/include or close to those line you will find a uikit foler in that folder u will see a folder called headers copy all the contents into /theos/include/uikit